# Is there a power equivalent to the Aether?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world, infinity-stones

**[The Marvel Wikia States](http://marvel.wikia.com/Aether):**

> The Aether is a mysterious force that existed before the birth of the
>   Nine Realms. It is known to be able to convert matter into dark
>   matter, and otherwise maintains an almost lifelike existence that
>   causes it to bond in a parasitic fashion to a living host. Once
>   bonded, the energies of the Aether slowly consume any mortal host, and
>   also have a volatile and deadly effect on any who come into contact
>   with the host in a manner that the Aether perceives as threatening.
>   Bonded with a stronger host that understands its power, the Aether can
>   be employed as a weapon where it lashes out with a concussive force,
>   or reaches out to convert matter.

[image]

In *Thor: the Dark World* the Aether is an Infinity Stone which can destroy the universe when an event called the Convergence happens. Unlike the others however [it exists is a liquid state says the Marvels Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Infinity_Gems).

We already know that it cannot be destroyed and can live in someone’s body, but is there a power equivalent to the Aether?

In my opinion maybe one of the other Infinity Stones has equivalent power, but I’m just asking because I don't know much about Thor, I do not know much about Infinity Stones and the Marvel Wikia doesn't really help.

Comment: Which universe are you referring to? Marvel Cinematic Universe or the comics? To be fair, *nobody* (outside of people working on the movies) knows much about most of the other Infinity Stones in the MCU as they are not the same as the ones in the comics. The Marvel Wikia article you cite even mentions that we don't know exactly which Infinity Gem/Stone the Aether actually is. It's difficult to identify something similar when we don't even know exactly what we're comparing.

Comment: @phantom42- That's a fair point. I wasn't actually aware that in Marvel Universe and the Comics, it different. I naturally assumed that they were the same as I am not quite sure and don't really know much about the Thor Universe. Sorry for your inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

@phantom42 has basically answered this in [his comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50160/is-there-a-power-equivalent-to-the-aether#comment94325_50160), but just for the record:

*Thor: the Dark World* introduced the Aether, as you described. In a mid-credits scene, it was taken by the Asgardians to a character called The Collector. They described it as an Infinity Stone, and explained that it would be dangerous for them to keep it when they already possessed another Infinity Stone, the Tesseract.

The Tesseract was key to the plot of *Captain America: the First Avenger* and *The Avengers*, where it was both a source of energy and a tool to open portals in space.

So far, that’s all the Infinity Stones we’ve seen in the [Marvel Cinematic Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe) (and it was only in *The Dark World’s* mid-credits scene that the Aether and the Tesseract were called that). We haven’t yet seen anything in the movies that has the same universe-destroying potential as the Aether — the Tesseract seemed to threaten Earth, but not the universe.

Doubtless we’ll find out more in the upcoming *[Guardians of the Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_(film))* movie (and possibly before that, in *[Captain America: the Winter Soldier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_The_Winter_Soldier)*).

In the comics, the Infinity Stones (or Infinity Gems, as they’re also called) have quite a long history. However, the movies generally don’t follow the comics in much detail*. For example, the Tesseract in the movies somewhat resembles the [Cosmic Cube](http://marvel.wikia.com/Cosmic_Cube) from the comics, but has not been described as such in the movies. There’s also [no Infinity Gem in the comics](http://marvel.wikia.com/Infinity_Gems#Capabilities) that particularly matches the capabilities of the Aether in *Thor: the Dark World*.

For further details, consult a [MacGuffin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin)ologist.

* (Which, given that there’s 50 years’ worth of often self-contradictory Marvel comics continuity out there, is unsurprising.)